# Django CMS background image rendering

Tags: django-templates, django-cms

I'm trying to render a background image using Django-cms for a personal blog. The background image is placed inside the a header class with site text in front as shown in the code below:

```
<!-- Page Header -->
<!-- Set your background image for this header on the line below. -->

<header class="intro-header" style="background-image:url("/static/img/imghome-bg.jpg")">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="site-heading">
                    <h1>Hey !</h1>
                    <hr class="small">
                    <span class="subheading">Latest Blog !</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

The background image is placed in side `/static/` directory with a sub file that i created called `/img/`.

I tried different using the render `static` tag (as shown below) but the image still doesn't appear.

`<header class="intro-header" style="background-image:url("{% static "/static/img/imghome-bg.jpg" %}")">`

The current results using the solutions above, as you you can see there is no background image only the text and the toolbar in white color. :

[image]

The overall results that i'm trying to get should look similar to this:

[image]

Any clue?

Comment: have you tried `static/` without the initial / ?

Comment: @petr Just tried. it's still the same. Just to clarify the `/static/` file is the default file that once you create a new djangocms new project from terminal using `$ djangocms -p projectname`. it's automatically created. The path of the `imghome-bg.jpg` is inside the following directory `/mydjangocmsprojectname/static/img`

Comment: *`/mydjangocmsprojectname/static/img/`

Comment: is the request for the image returning a 404?

Comment: @Paulo There is no request for the image. The only request back is the white background that is show my question above.

Comment: The proper way IMO would be to place the static files in the app directory. If your app is called `myapp`, then you would create this directory structure: `myapp/static/myapp/img/`. In your HTML template you should therefore write "/myapp/static/img/imghome-bg.jpg". Here `myapp` is the app name, and it is inside your project directory. I know this won't solve your problem, the intention is just to point out an another approach.

Answer (score 2):

When using the `static` template tag you need to drop the `/static/` part of the path. When configured correctly the static tag should add the correct first part of the path.

I suggest you try

```
<header class="intro-header" style="background-image:url({% static 'img/imghome-bg.jpg' %})">
```

For details see the [staticfiles app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/staticfiles/). Most relevant part of the configuration (in your projects's `settings.py`) are `STATIC_URL` (should be `/static/`in your case, it seems) and `STATIC_ROOT`(which points to the directory where static file are collected).

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
<header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url({% static 'img/imghome-bg.jpg' %})">
```

your syntax might not be correct.

Comment: sorry my code got removed, it should read "background-image: url({% static 'img/imghome-bg.jpg' %})">